# Radiobutton disabling in gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a Itemtemplate column in Gridview in which there are 3 radio buttons. I want to capture 
and store the radiobutton clicked in a flag variable. So that next time it is disabled and other radio button is automatically enabled? Can you please help

Comment: Can you share some code, please?

Comment: @Melanie I dont know how to start itself. Its new to me for gridView

Answer (score 0):

You must make the  AutoPostback property of the particular Radio button true..

Then you can write the code sample as follows...

You must write the code in checked changed event of the particular Radio button...

protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
    foreach (GridViewRow i in Gridviewbrands.Rows)
    {

        RadioButton Rd = (RadioButton)i.FindControl("RadioButton2");
        if (Rd.Checked == true)
        {
            Rd.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```